# How to display commas in italics after journal and volume number with apacite bibliography style?

Tags: bibliographies, italic, apa6, apacite

In APA6 style,  commas after the journal name and after the volume number (if there is no issue number) should be italicized in reference list. However, the basic apacite package do not take care of it... How can I change this?

My `text` file looks as follow:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,apacite]{apa6}
\input{preamble}
\input{firstpage}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

---

My `bib` file looks as follow:

```
@article{homan1987cerebral,
  title={Cerebral location of international 10--20 system electrode placement},
  author={Homan, Richard W and Herman, John and Purdy, Phillip},
  doi={10.1016/0013-4694(87)90206-9},
  journal={Electroencephalography and Clinical Neurophysiology},
  volume={66},
  number={4},
  pages={376--382},
  year={1987},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{tak2013statistical,
  title={Statistical analysis of fNIRS data: a comprehensive review},
  author={Tak, Sungho and Ye, Jong Chul},
  doi={10.1016/j.neuroimage.2013.06.016},
  journal={Neuroimage},
  volume={85},
  pages={72--91},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

---

If anyone could help me, it would be great, because this is driving me crazy!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: For future questions you may want to try and make your (already very good) MWE even better: Keep in mind that we don't have access to your files `preamble.tex` and `firstpage.tex`, so the lines `\input{preamble}\input{firstpage}` produce an error when we run the MWE. In this case it would have been enough to replace them with `\shorttitle{Foo}` to avoid any errors. To catch things like this I always recommend to test-run MWEs in an empty folder before submission.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I did not specify those files because I thought they were not useful for this kind of issue. But now, I see that it is actually helpful to run the MWE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apacite` uses the macro `\APACjournalVolNumPages` to style `journal`, `volume`, `number` and `pages`.

The following redefinition should work

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,apacite]{apa6}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\APACjournalVolNumPages}[4]{%
  \Bem{#1%
    \ifx\@empty#2#3#4\@empty
    \else
    ,
    \fi
  }%             journal
  \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
  \else
    \Bem{#2%
      \ifx\@empty#3\@empty
      ,
      \else
      \fi
    }%  volume
  \fi
  \ifx\@empty#3\@empty
  \else
    \unskip({#3}), %      issue number
  \fi
  \ifx\@empty#4\@empty
  \else
    {#4}%      pages
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{homan1987cerebral,
  title   = {Cerebral Location of International 10--20 System Electrode Placement},
  author  = {Homan, Richard W. and Herman, John and Purdy, Phillip},
  doi     = {10.1016/0013-4694(87)90206-9},
  journal = {Electroencephalography and Clinical Neurophysiology},
  volume  = {66},
  number  = {4},
  pages   = {376--382},
  year    = {1987},
}
@article{tak2013statistical,
  title   = {Statistical Analysis of {fNIRS} Data: A Comprehensive Review},
  author  = {Tak, Sungho and Ye, Jong Chul},
  doi     = {10.1016/j.neuroimage.2013.06.016},
  journal = {Neuroimage},
  volume  = {85},
  pages   = {72--91},
  year    = {2013},
}
\end{filecontents}
\shorttitle{Lorem}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: The commas directly after the italic journal and the italic volume number are also in italics.]

In case you are using `biblatex` (`biblatex-apa`) you want to set the `punctfont` option.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,biblatex]{apa6}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{punctfont}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{homan1987cerebral,
  title   = {Cerebral Location of International 10--20 System Electrode Placement},
  author  = {Homan, Richard W. and Herman, John and Purdy, Phillip},
  doi     = {10.1016/0013-4694(87)90206-9},
  journal = {Electroencephalography and Clinical Neurophysiology},
  volume  = {66},
  number  = {4},
  pages   = {376--382},
  year    = {1987},
}
@article{tak2013statistical,
  title   = {Statistical Analysis of {fNIRS} Data: A Comprehensive Review},
  author  = {Tak, Sungho and Ye, Jong Chul},
  doi     = {10.1016/j.neuroimage.2013.06.016},
  journal = {Neuroimage},
  volume  = {85},
  pages   = {72--91},
  year    = {2013},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\shorttitle{Lorem}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The commas directly after the italic journal and the italic volume number are also in italics.]

Or, more explicitly, if `biblatex` is not loaded via the document class

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, punctfont]{biblatex}
```

Comment: +1. Nice touch to encase `fNIRS` in curly braces! :-)